# Show Dialogfragment on lock screen

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, lockscreen, keyguard

I'm trying to show a DialogFragment over lock screen.
This has to happen when a user triggers an action via the new keyguard widget function.

In particular it's a timepicker dialog that's shown, but the user only sees it if he unlocks the screen. How do i manage to show it even if the screen's locked?

I already tried all combinations of this flags, but without success:

```
AlertDialog dialog = dBuilder.create();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

This is called in onCreateView.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Sorry, didn't have the time to try it yet. I will accept your answer when I did. Thank you very much for giving me a hint!

Answer (score 1):

Dialog windows do not show on the lock screen because they are floating windows, I can't give you an actual reason as to why Android doesn't show them, but it might have to do with drawing the underlying lock screen components, since those are, for all intents and purposes "secure components".

Having dealt with your problem before, what I ended up doing was making a separate activity, setting your above window flags to the Activity's window using`Activity.getWindow().setFlags()` then showing my DialogFragment. It isn't pretty, but it seems like the closest thing that will *reliably* work when set up properly. Luckily UI-wise you can set the Activity's theme to be `Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar` which looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

This Code is working if you are using dialog fragment.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        PowerManager powerMgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerMgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                "noti");
        KeyguardManager keyMgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        keyLock = keyMgr.newKeyguardLock("noti");
keyLock.disableKeyguard();

wakeLock.acquire();
```

---

sorry about bad code formatting.